# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar los estilos del mensaje de error que me aparece cuando hay un error en el recaptcha versión 3?

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

Hola comunidad
Me surgió un problema, espero contar con su ayuda.
Estoy implementado **recaptcha versión 3** en una aplicación web usando la librería [react-google-recaptcha-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha-v3?activeTab=readme) y estoy probando los posibles errores que me pueda mandar el recaptcha, como por ejemplo cuándo no hay internet, el token ha expirado, el usuario usa una vpn, etc. Pero con algunos errores, especialmente cuando uso una vpn aparece un mensaje de error en la parte inferior de mi aplicación, el cuál es este: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
El fondo de mi aplicación en blanco, por lo cuál quisiera cambiar la posición de este mensaje y el color porque no va de acuerdo a los colores que estoy usando.
Si alguien ha experimentado algo similar y pudo resolver esto me podría decir como le hizo porfavor?